# Nginx dynamic proxy - without re-compile

Tags: nginx

I have an Nginx container which gets request on URLs matching:

```
http://nginx/cometd/{operator}/{gameKey}
```

I'd like to proxy the requests elsewhere,

```
http://{gameTemlpateId}/cometd/{operator}/{gameKey}
```

Theres is a REST endpoint I can use to find out the hostname:

```
http://config-system/{operator}/{gameKey}
```

That returns JSON:

```
{"gameTemplateId": "foo"}
```

I've seen examples using LUA that do this, but they require you to re-compile Nginx. I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: What system do you have? Probably you already have lua or something like that…

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Server Fault.

On Ubuntu, install the `nginx-extras` package. It includes the Lua module among others.  If the Lua package is all you need, there is no re-compiling involved for this.